# WAL sequence number infinite?

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, postgresql, db2

I am wondering if database WAL sequences are infinite? I guess most WAL records have a fix size for the WAL number? Is this a really big number that is so big that it just won't reach an end? This might be quite a waste of space? Or have the big DB-player invented a better method?

Or do they implement some logic to let the WAl start at 0 again? That might have heavy impact on many spots in the code...?

EDIT:

**Impact:** E.g. the recovery after a crash relies on the sequence number getting bigger along the timeline. If the sequence could start over the recovery could get confused.

**Term WAL sequence number:** WAL (Write Ahead Log a.k.a the transactional log that is guranteed to be on your disk before the application layer received that a transaction was successful). This log has a growing number to keep the database consitent e.g. in case of recovery by checking the WAL sequence number from the pages against the sequence number from the WAL.

Comment: Show the possible impact scenarios, please.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen the term "WAL sequence" used before and Google isn't returning anything obviously database related.  Can you define that term for us?

Comment: @JustinCave - googling WAL, this appears to be a PostgreSQL term for "Write-Ahead Logging".  I don't understand why this was tagged with `Oracle`.

Comment: @BobJarvis The term is just and abbreviation. All ACID databases use WALs. This question could have also been tagged DB2, MSSQL or whatever. I am interested in any implemenation details of any ACID database. Presumably they will all have the same strategy anyway...

Comment: @Franz Kafka: just for the record, not all ACID databases use WAL. A few use [shadow paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_paging).

Comment: btw, no significant RDBMS I know of employs shadow paging, but the technique is making a come back due to the rise of functional programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not assume that every database implements the same strategy.

Speaking only for Oracle, the SCN (system change number) is a 48-bit number so an Oracle database can handle nearly 300 trillion transactions before hitting the limit.  Realistically, that will take eons.  Even if you could do 1 thousand transactions per second, the SCN wouldn't hit the limit for 300 billion seconds or roughly 9500 years.  Now, there are various things that can cause the SCN to increment in addition to just doing transactions (famously the [recent issue with hot backups and database links](http://www.infoworld.com/d/security/fundamental-oracle-flaw-revealed-184163-0?page=0,1) that caused a few users to exceed the database's checks for the reasonability of the SCN) so it won't really take 9500 years to hit the limit.  But, realistically, it gives Oracle plenty of time to move to a 64-bit SCN some years down the line, buying everyone a few more centuries of functionality.

Comment: I think the WAL sequence in PostgreSQL is something different than Oracle's SCN. PostgreSQL's WAL is somewhat similar to Oracle's REDO logs.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - The SCN should be recorded in the redo logs, though.  Is there another component of the redo logs in Oracle that I'm not thinking of that would be more similar to the PostgreSQL WAL sequence?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the (logging) internals of both so I might be completely mistaken: I **think** Oracles "Log Sequence Numbers" is a better match to the WAL sequence. But again: I'm absolutely not sure. On the other hand. PostgreSQL's `ctid` is a good match for Oracle's `SCN` as both define a "transaction order", if that is what you meant

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: ctid is the tuple ID, consisting of the block number an tuple line pointer number of a tuple within a table. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/ddl-system-columns.html LSN is the log sequence number.  http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/include/access/xlogdefs.h;h=5e6d7e600bdd1dcc7a70b52d96e47feef757fb8b;hb=HEAD#l17  As you can see, the PostgreSQL LSN is made up of two 32-bit integers; the way these are used it won't take quite as long as using up a 64-bit counter, but close.

Comment: @kgrittn: of course you are right. I actually wanted to write `xid`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Ah, OK.  Just for the record: an xid is only 32 bits and wraps around by design; xid values are *frozen* before wraparound renders their meaning ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Like SQL Server, DB2 calls that counter a [Log Sequence Number](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0057411.html) (LSN). IBM recently expanded the size of their LSN from six bytes to eight bytes, unsigned. The LSN is an ever-growing pointer that shows where in the log files that specific log record can be found. An eight byte LSN means that a DB2 database can write nearly 16 [exbibytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exbibyte) of log records before running out of address space, at which point the contents of the database must be unloaded and copied into a new database.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres WAL numbers technically can overflow, but only after writing 32 Eb of data, as the WAL file pointer is 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

See [What is an LSN: Log Sequence Number](http://rusanu.com/2012/01/17/what-is-an-lsn-log-sequence-number/). The article describes the structure of the SQL Server LSN (the WAL number) and shows you how to decode one. Since LSNs are of fixed size and they don't roll over, it follows that you can run out of them. It will take a very very long time though.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, WAL logs are stored as a [set of segment files](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/wal-internals.html). "Segment files are given ever-increasing numbers as names, starting at 000000010000000000000000." The number doesn't wrap around.